How לִקַּטְתְּ should be read
When reading Meghilath Ruth, How should I read the word לִקַּטְתְּ in 2:19?
Should I attempt to pronounce the ט separately from the תּ (which, as far as I know, isn’t possible without an awkward-sounding pause)?
Should I start with ט and release the sound as תּ?
Something else?
(Just to be clear, the second option is possible because my Minhag is to pronounce the two differently).

Maybe practice option 1 more

Ask someone from your minhag. As an Ashkenazi, I do option 1.
